# Spring JPA query for many to many

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity User and System

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class System{
    private Long id;
    private Long SystemId;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

and one table created by hibernate legalhold_system

I want to get all the user related to System ID, I can fetch the same using below native query

```
select * from user where id in (select user_id from legalhold_system where system_id in(select id from system_user where system_id=:1))
```

How can I achieve the same with Spring JPA query, As I don't have legalhold_system entity present in Code?

Comment: You can always use native queru for tthat with @Query

Comment: Yes, I can but is it possible with Spring JPA query instead of native query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are the only two entities, it should be doable using this query:

```
SELECT s.users FROM System s WHERE s.systemId = :systemId
```